# Writing to remote stream while reading from a remote stream in node js

Tags: node.js, node-streams

I need to post a file in form-data to a server which accepts a readstream. The data to be posted is available in another server. How do i download the data from server A and stream it to server B in node js?

```
var req = require('request');
var fs = require('fs');
        
        // download             

        var downloadStream = fs.createWriteStream("c:\\file\\test.zip");
        request = req("urlA");
        request.pipe(downloadStream);
        
        // upload
        
        var uploadStream = fs.createReadStrean("c:\\file\\test.zip");
        var options = {
                        url: "urlB",                        
                        headers: {                          
                            "Content-type": "multipart/form-data",
                        },
                        formData:{
                            zippedSource: uploadStream
                        }                       
                    };
        
        req.post(options).then(function (res) {
            console.log("DONE");
        });
```

Also, while downloading with above code. The download abruptly stops in middle saying ECONNRESET for large files (size over 1GB).

Comment: Please show your relevant code so answers can be crafted that fit your specific scenario.  The generic answer is you use `.pipe()` to pipe a readstream into a writestream.

Comment: @jfriend00 I have updated the sample code

Comment: First off, you have to wait until the `.pipe()` is done before trying to read the resulting file.  Use the `finish` event on the write stream to know when it's done writing.